# Signora or Signorina when marriage status unknown

Tags: pronouns, letter-writing

I am writing an email in Italian to a female HR manager. I was going to write "Buongiorno Sig.ra ____", but I don't know if this would be proper given that she may not be married. What is proper in this situation?

Comment: [Related question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11334/would-italians-refer-to-an-american-or-foreign-woman-as-signora/11335#11335)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably neither. Since in Italian whoever as a *laurea* (the lowest universitary degree) is entitled to be called *dottore*, or *dottoressa* for a female, chances are that whoever holds a high-level post in a firm or other organisation has this title. So to be on the safe, you may use *dott.* for a male and *dott.ssa* (or *dott.*) for a female.

As for *signora* / *signorina*, the use of the latter is dwindling, and the trend is towards a generalised use of *signora*, whatever the marital status of the woman involved. For more on this, if your Italian is good enough, see, on the website of Accademia della Crusca, what [linguist Paolo D'Achille explains](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/signora-o-signorina/1253).

Comment: Note that Dag is from Rome, an area where in some contexts it is not uncommon to call *dotto'* even random people you meet on the road, as a sign of respect.

Comment: Thanks, @FedericoPoloni, but also note that DaG is able to distinguish between popular or jocular use, and formal and standard one, _secco_. ;)

Comment: Sure, no offense implied. This was just to note that the frequency of *dottore* may vary across regions.

Comment: Fair point, but the use of _dotto'_ or _dottore_ as an everyday appellation is not the same thing as its formal use in correspondence between strangers. In some parts of the South, _marescia'_ is used as a generalised form of address, but this doesn't detract from the fact that an actual _maresciallo_ (who isn't a friend of yours) is still to be called _maresciallo_.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most common solution is avoiding the problem by using a different salutation (for instance, just *buongiorno*) or switching to a first-name basis earlier than normal practice would suggest (in particular, *gentile Anna* would sound perfectly OK between coworkers in a firm with a relaxed culture).

I don't tend to 'doctor' people I don't know, and I very seldom look their title up. But that might just be a cultural preference; I can see other people doing differently, in contexts where degrees have a higher perceived importance.

Answer (score 0):

You usually start formal letters with "**gentile**" (literally kind), which can be followed by the recipient's "**titolo**" (title, qualification). If someone is in a public position they will usually have some sort of profile online that tells you what their qualifications are. Check that and write "**dottoressa**" (f. graduate) if she has a degree, or you can also write  "**professoressa**" (f. professor) if she teaches. You have to check though, if she doesn't actually have a degree it would be awkward to call her dottoressa.

Even if she has no qualification I would avoid "signora" or "signorina" and simply go for "gentile" + her name and surname, in this order. "Signora" and "signorina" feel dated and there's always a chance you make her feel old or weird if you use the wrong one. If your tone is right your letter can sound formal and polite enough even without "signora"/"signorina".

Comment: All good advice, but I find, say, “Gentile Maria Rossi” a slightly odd mix of formalism and colloquialism and personally I'd avoid it with someone I don't already know.